# path for the application data in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, forms, winforms, xamarin

In C# Windows Forms, `System.Windows.Forms.Application.LocalUserAppDataPath` gives the path for the application data of a local, non-roaming user. What is its equivalent in a Xamarin Android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.Essentials has a method called `FileSystem.AppDataDirectory` :

- Android : AppDataDirectory – Returns the FilesDir of the current context
- iOS : AppDataDirectory – Returns the Library directory
- UWP: AppDataDirectory – Returns the LocalFolder directory

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=uwp

If you do not want to use Xamarin.Essentials package, you can just use the source code for the Android implementation:

re: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/main/Xamarin.Essentials/FileSystem/FileSystem.android.cs

Or the Xamarin.Android docs for `FilesDir` and using `System.Environment.SpecialFolder` and their Android paths within your app's sandbox:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#working-with-internal-storage